# How to bind a function to an element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip, bind

I am using the miniTip jQuery Plugin: http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/81/miniTip-jQuery-Plugin

It is working with the following code:

```
$('#primary').on('hover', function() {

    $('.tooltip').miniTip({
        offset:30
    })
});
```

However, when I load some content with ajax, the plugin stops working. Is there a way I can bind it so it reloads when I load the new content?

Comment: can you post sample html code where you want to disolay tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin does not "stop working", is simply does not know about the newly added elements. Given your relevant code fires inside a hover event on `#primary`, I have to assume that the element with `id="primary"` is loaded dynamically, otherwise it *should* have still worked.

*If* that is the case, you can simply change your `hover` event to use a *delegated event handler*, attached to a *non-changing ancestor element*.

e.g.

```
$(document).on('hover', '#primary', function() {

    $('.tooltip').miniTip({
        offset:30
    })
});
```

Delegated events delegate responsibility for the event handling to an ancestor. The ancestor listens for that event (e.g. `hover`) bubbling up from descendant element, *then* applies the jQuery filter. The function is *then* applied to *any matching descendant element that caused the event*.

This means that the elements matching the selector only need to exist at event time (and not at event registration time, e.g. on DOM ready).

**Notes:**

- Always use `document` as the default if no convenient ancestor is closer. `'body'` has a bug relating to styling (if it has a *calculated height of 0* it will not get mouse events at all!).
- If this does not work for you, you need to provide the rest of your code as the problem may be something unrelated (duplicate element IDs, error in loading code etc)